# Input mask to make optional zip+4 display hyphen optional

Tags: vba, ms-access

Purpose:

To make the hyphen in the zip+4 not display if +4 data isn't present (I also want to apply the same logic to an optional area code and extension in my phone number field).

I have the following VBA for my input mask (I've tried GetFocus(), BeforeUpdate(), AfterUpdate() and LostFocus() for my events):

```
Private Sub Zip_LostFocus()
    'Display hyphen (-) only if using "Plus-4" zip code
    If Len([Zip]) <= 5 Then
        Me.[Zip].InputMask = "00000;;_"
    End If
    If Len([Zip]) > 5 Then
        Me.[Zip].InputMask = "00000\-9999;;_"
    Else
    End If
End Sub
```

I am having the devil of a time finding help on this.
I appreciate anything anyone can contribute to a solution for my "obsession."

erandalln

P.S.: Now I know why I couldn't find "inputmask" in my search-need a 1500 rep to create a new 'tag'; the existing one is "input-mask".

Comment: Why do you need a mask?  Couldn't you just do a sub string if <= 5 or a "left(5)"?

Comment: Would that avoid the hyphen in display strings of 5, but include it in strings of 9? I want to avoid storing the hard-coded characters ('-', in zip codes; '(',')' and 'x', in phone numbers).  If I write the entire procedure in VB, will I invite security issues?

Comment: You wouldn't get any special characters unless they exist in the first 5 characters.  If these are all valid US based zip codes only and you haven't suppressed leading zeros it shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: The user would have to input the hyphen in a zip+4 entry?

Comment: In a properly formatted US zip+4 wouldn't the hyphen be the sixth character....

Comment: Yes, which means that if the user chose to enter a properly fomatted zip+4, he/she would(?) have to enter the hyphen.  I'm trying to avoid that and use the resulting technique in the phone number field relative to optional area code and extension data. The optionality is a customer (in this case textbook) requirement, the final display characteristics are my desire to increase the professional looks of the final product.